# extract a variable's name from string in python

Tags: python, string.format

I want to do something like this in Python:

```
a_string = 'variable_name'
print('{0}'.format(variable_name))
```

That is, I want to extract a variable's name from the string and send it into .format().
How can I do?

Comment: What do you want to be printed here?

Comment: if you have data in your variable names, [you shouldn't](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Answer (score 4):

This, in general, is not considered a good practice - 
data should be data, and code should be code. There are, of course, exceptions
to that general rule.

To do what you want, you can simply access the dictionary returned 
by a call to `vars`:

```
a_string = 'variable_name'
print('{0}'.format(vars()[variable_name]))
```

`vars` checks the variable availability in the local context (the same as a call to `locals()`)

Back to good practices: if you need strings to locate data in your program, you should check if you could not be using a dictionary instead of letting this data, with dynamic name, directly in a variable. One of the main purposes of dictionaries is allowing dynamic look-up of data.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way is to use the dictionary form of `str.format`

```
>>> variable_name = 'hello'
>>> print('{variable_name}'.format(**vars()))
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as:

```
a_string = 'variable_name'
print('{0}'.format(globals()[a_string]))
```

#### Example

```
variable_name = 'hello'

a_string = 'variable_name'
>>> print('{0}'.format(globals()[a_string]))
hello
```